# After javascript menu function triggered, responsive css menu element dissapears. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript hamburger menu that condenses below 800px. Everything works as planned until I reach this failure point:

Once the onclick is activated twice (to open and close the menu), if the browser is resized to larger than 800px all elements of the menu disappear. Why?

The responsive style resumes as normal once sized below the width threshold. If the onclick is not activated there is no problem with the css rules.

I am testing in firefox, chrome, and safari on a Mac.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* main semantic rules */

html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: normal;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  color: rgba(29, 29, 29, .8);
}

a:hover {
  color: #f5df4d;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  color: 000000;
}

.nav_container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo_container {
  height: 6em;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}


/* Top Bar Java Menu Style Rules */

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 3em;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #f7f6f5;
  display: block;
}

.overlay a:hover {
  webkit-transform: translate(0px, -3px);
  transform: translate(0px, -3px);
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.fa-bars {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}


/*End Java Menu Rules*/

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }
  .overlay {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    margin: auto 0;
    width: relative;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
  }
  .overlay a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: 000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .overlay-content {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 1em;
    top: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- Icon for hamburger menu (bars) and twitter logo -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="help.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="nav_container">
    <div class="logo_container">
      <!-- Contains a linked logo .svg -->
    </div>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="">A</a>
        <a href="">B</a>
        <a href="">C</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `closeNav()` function hides your navigation by putting a style attribute on it with `display:none;`, but this will persist when you resize the browser to a larger width.

So when you resize your browser the navigation will still be hidden because the style attribute will override the css you wrote.

You can fix this by changing your `closeNav()` function to:

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "";
}
```

This will clear the display style so your css will be used again.